# Error with LONG data type in cursor

Tags: oracle

I am trying to generate a spool file through anonymous block below in order to find out views on a particular table.

```
declare
cursor c1 is select view_name,text from users_view;
rt c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into rt;
exit when c1%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(rt.view_name || '|' || rt.text);
end loop;
end;
```

When I run it, I get an error like "numeric or value errors", however if I remove text(LONG) column from cursor definition the block goes through without any error.

I understand that we can not use LONG data type in a where clause but is it that it can't be fetched in a cursor as well? If yes, what can be the alternative in this case?

Comment: This is PL/SQL right?

Comment: A long can be fetched in a cursor, but will get that error if it's larger then 32k characters. Is there a reason you want to do this inside an anonymnous block rather than as a simple select?

Comment: Does 'in order to find out views on a particular table' mean you plan to parse the text of all the view to find references within them to a specific table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly addressing the `long` issue, but if you want to find out which views refer to a particular table, rather than searching through the view source you can query the data dictionary:

```
select owner, type, name
from all_dependencies
where referenced_type = 'TABLE'
and referenced_owner = user -- or a specific schema
and referenced_name = '<my_table_name>';
```

This will also list any triggers on the table, etc., so if you are only interested in view you can add `and type = 'VIEW'`.

Of course, this may just give you a smaller list of views to examine in more detail to see how the table is used by each one, but it's easier than searching all 300 of your views manually... and it might mean you don't need to get the text of the large views with more than 32k characters which are causing the `long` problem in the first place.

Comment: I had eventually got it through dba_dependencies, but just wanted to understand this cursor situation.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>In this case the error indicates that you've hit the buffer limit - `dbms_output.put_line` wont handle such large amount of data.</strike>

After looking at the problem more closely, it's not the `dbms_output.put_line` issue, not yet, it's the, as Alex Poole has pointed out in the comment to your question, it's the cursor problem. So I would suggest you to use simple Select statement(option #2 in the answer). If you go for a workaround

```
create table <<name>> as 
  select view_name
       , to_lob(text) 
   from user_views
```

for example, you will be able to use cursor but then `dbms_output.put_line` will stop you

To generate a spool file you have at least two options:

1. Use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) package to write data to a file.
2. Let SQL*PLUS do the job. For example:

   ```
   set feedback off;
   set termout off;
   set colsep "|";
   set long 20000;   -- increase the size if it's not enough
   set heading off;
   set linesize 150; -- increase the size if it's not enough


   spool <<file path\file name>>

   select view_name
        , text
     from user_views

   spool off;
   ```

At the end you will have a similar output in your `<<file path\file name>>` file:

```
ALL_APPLY_CONFLICT_COLUMNS    |select c.object_owner, 
                              |       c.object_name,
                              |       c.method_name,
                              |       c.resolution_column, c.column_name,
                              |       c.apply_database_link
                              |  from all_tab_columns o, 
                              |       dba_apply_conflict_columns c
                              | where c.object_owner = o.owner
                              |   and c.object_name = o.table_name   
                              |   and c.column_name = o.column_name
```

Comment: Seems like it is not with dbms_ouput, because I get the same error even on replacing it with `dbms_ouput.put_line('hi')`. In all there are some 300 records, printing hi 300 times should not be an issue. Please advise.

Comment: @iceman29 - the `dbms_output` buffer [is unlimited](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#CIHEGBBF), since 10g I think, but the maximum line size would still be a problem; you could output the `clob` in chunks though. Only if there's a compelling reason not to use a simple select, of course, and if there is then `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` might be a simpler route.

Comment: @AlexPoole Simple select can't be used because long doesn't work in where clause(I read about it after it didn't work for me). Please suggest if there is still a way to use it.